# Is there a design pattern for ActiveRecord structure?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I want to know the structure about ruby's `ActiveRecord`. But I didn't find a design or introduction for its architecture.

Other way, how can I know its structure or how to read its source code to fast understand it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of the talk Gregg Pollack gave at the Lone Star Ruby Conference about the big refactoring of Rails 3.  He does a great presentation gives you a great peek under the skirt of Rails.  Rails 4 hasn't really changed much.  Active record follows the same architecture he describes and you will be able to see it when you browse through the active record code after seeing the presentation.  Here is the link to the talk:

http://confreaks.tv/videos/lsrc2010-de

or

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ldxGXxZ1CCI